# Highlighted errors on VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Suddenly, the way to analyze and display errors in vscode changed. From today it marks the entire function block as an error, which is annoying because it becomes very confusing.
I do not know if without intention I pressed a shortcut, or some combination of keys. Does anyone know how to return to the previous mode?

Thanks a lot.

[image: how the errors were displayed previously and now.]

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow's mechanism for displaying images to show your pictures.

Comment: What language mode is displayed in the status bar?

Comment: When you hover over the squigglies, what error is reported?

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález, the language is dart. In both cases. Thanks!

Comment: HI @Mark, the error is the same on both examples (are 2 different computers, with the same VSCode version), 'undefined name ti'. That is because I'm in the middle of the typing. Thanks

Comment: This error is all over my code... not sure what was the cause.

Comment: @EngineSense I found the problem. On Settings.json. This line "dart.previewLsp": true.

Answer (score 0):

Before LSP, the error range was being [accidentally truncated to a single line](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/6ac0f15e955c73cfe9adcc41966cdc46824d031f/src/extension/providers/dart_diagnostic_provider.ts#L44). With LSP the complete region is used, which means you now see the actual range produced by the analyzer.

Turning off LSP is only a short-term fix as it will soon became the default (and only) option, so if you think the shorter ranges are better, please file an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk for some discussion. Thanks!